# Parsing information from HTML table PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to parse a table from a website. Which is like :
[image]

Desired result I want is something like that :
[image]

How to achieve it.

Table is made up of simple `<tr>` `<td>` tags and used `rowspan` and `colspan` for spacing.

How to achieve it in PHP or JS?

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question and include the relevant source code to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP, use DOMDocument.

```
foreach((@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html))->getElementsByTagName("tr") as $tr){
    foreach($tr->getElementsByTagName("td") as $td){
        var_dump($td->textContent);
    }    
}
```

in Javascript, use DOMParser.

```
var doc=(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(html,"text/html");
var all=doc.querySelectorAll("tr > td");
for(var i=0;i<all.length;++i){
    console.log(all[i].textContent);
}
```